# Mysterious CUDA profiler error

Tags: cuda, profiler, nvidia, gpu

So I have successfully installed the CUDA toolkit and GPU computing SDK on a Mac Pro running OS X version 10.6.6.  The sample CUDA programs provided with the SDK as well as some programs of my own work well.  However, when I run any of these CUDA programs through the NVIDIA Visual Profiler (the executable is called computeprof), I always get the following error upon launch:

"Unable to initialize the Profiling in Start/Stop mode"

NVIDIA's documentation does not mention this error, and Googling shows a single post in the NVIDIA forums in which several people have run into this problem recently (since October 2010) but no solutions.

Any information on this error message would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just scanned through [the doc](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/VisualProfiler/Compute_Visual_Profiler_User_Guide.pdf). There are lots of features not supported on OS X. It doesn't say so, but chances are manual start/stop is among them. BTW, the profiler doesn't appear to do stack sampling.

Comment: Mike: Could you re-post your comment as a reply, so that nedblorf can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If Visual Profiler v4.0 isn't working for you, there's a new CUDA release out (v4.1) and it includes a completely new & re-designed Visual Profiler.

The new NVIDIA Visual Profiler (v4.1) supports automated performance analysis to identify performance improvement opportunities in your application. It also links directly to the most useful sections of the Best Practices Guide for the issues it detects. And the Visual Profiler is available for free as part of the CUDA Toolkit on NVIDIA's developer web site: http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda.

If you experience any problems, please file a bug via your (free) NVIDIA registered developer account so the team working on the Visual Profiler can figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CUDA4.0?
I had problem with CUDA 4.0 and visual profiler (I use a Linux system). But it works fine with CUDA 3.2.